# Minimal Effort Database Abstraction Layer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, abstraction

Hey i'm working on a small project, for all intents and purposes i'm gonna be using mongodb however as practice i want to make use of a database abstraction layer (that requires minimal effort). I came up with this:

*db.js:*

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose', { useNewUrlParser: true})
const {credentials} = require('../../config');
const { connectionString } = credentials.mongo;
const User = require('../../models/user')
if (!connectionString){
    console.error("MongoDB connection string missing!")
    process.exit(1)
}
mongoose.connect(connectionString, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
const mongoLink = mongoose.connection
mongoLink.on('error', err=>{
    console.error("MongoDB error: " + err.message);
})
mongoLink.once('open', () => console.log('MongoDB connection established'))

function abstractFromDatabase(model){
    return {
        findOne : (async function() {
            return model.findOne(...arguments).lean()
        }),
        findMany : (async function() {
            return model.findMany(...arguments).lean() 
        })
        //... more primitive functions here
    }
}

module.exports.User = abstractFromDatabase(User)
//adding functions specific to model here
module.exports.User.getAllRelatedUsers = (async function() {
    //...

})
//...export more database functionality
```

I'm aware that this is not a very good level of abstraction but if i ever wanted to migrate to another database technology it would still give me the interface to do so and I want  something that is fast and easy to implement, could this work? Is there any major downsides i'm not considering?

Comment: I have tried this on a project before, the idea behind it(being able to change the data layer without touching the business logic) is cool, however, it's a lot of trouble, at a point it felt like I was re-writing the mongoose library in a way. I was able to abstract all the methods the application uses, however, I don't think I would do such again on another project, unless it is an un-arguable requirement from project owners, I would prefer waiting till this hypothetical scenario of changing the data layer of the application happens, then I would figure out the best fix to apply.

Comment: Some of the things I believe you are not considering: (1)From what I see above, your application still needs to be mongoose-aware because when it calls the findOne(or any other abstracted methods), it has to pass the arguments just the way mongoose expects it so when you change your data layer to use maybe firebase, you would also have to update the calling code. (2)More than often, you would want to extend the mongoose query with methods like `select`, `limit`, `skip`, `populate` etc. I don’t think this abstraction is taking care of that.

Comment: I guess I should have elaborated a bit more, I was aware of both these problems, however the idea was to limit my usage of these "advanced queries" when calling functions from db.js however I came to the conclusion that it's super wonky to have an interface that provides more functionality than you are allowed to use, (kind of defeats the purpose of an interface). Also I came to the conclusion that projects where the desire for a database abstraction layer are big enough for you to implement one but at the same time you don't want to put more effort like i proposed don't exist.

Comment: TL;DR I think it's too lazy and I don't think it adds any value other than being able to say "IN THEORY i have a database abstraction layer"